# How does the fossil connect with the rest of the story?

Tags: utawarerumono

During the game there is a scene where someone discovers a fossil of the Utawarerumono (apparently an archeologist) and it's hinted that the Utawarerumono is the missing link between man and ape or the origin of man. The fossil has what looks to be Hakuro's mask on it as well. The archeologist is then shot by the person he was talking to, apparently a guard.

Now we know that the "Iceman" is the Utawarerumono (Hakuro) and he was being experimented on so that humanity could become stronger to inhabit the world. However I don't understand where the scene with the fossil fits in.

So I am wondering, what the connection between the fossil and the rest of the story is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how game presents it, but I think it is pretty obvious from anime.

The scene with the fossil is in our present.

> The scientists find the fossil and believe it is missing link between man and ape. Proto-Hakuoro finds it and wants to show it to the world. But another scientist, tells him that humanity is not yet ready for such revelation and shoots him. His blood gets on the fossil, which awakens Utawarerumono. It then asks the dying scientists if he wants to live. He agrees and gives his body as vessel to the Utawarerumono, thus gaining the mask and practically becoming Utawarerumono.

Fast forward few (hundreds) years

> and Proto-Hakuoro is found as Iceman.

Neither game nor anime explains where the Utawarerumono actually came from and how it became a fossil.

Comment: I wasn't really asking where Utawarerumono came from, it's just that in the Visual Novel the only connection you could get from it it is that one of the 2 people there had Hakuro's voice but that's only evident if your using voices from the PS2 game, however your answer does explain the link since the Visual Novel never indicates when the fossil scene takes place and it does make sense if one of the scientists was Hakuro centuries before being discovered as Iceman